# Translate custom template with WPML

Tags: customization, templates, translation, plugin-wpml

I have custom template that is used by ClassiPress and it is working fine on default language, but when I enter the page language selector won't work since it's not translated.

How can I translate custom page template with WPML so that language selector will work?

Answer (score 1):

To translate custom page templates you must select "Synchronize page template" in WPML options. For it to actually work the page template markup must be localized or internationalized using a recognized format, for example http://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers, and then have an accompanying .mo/.po file . WPML also has an addon called "String Translation module" which can scan for "stuff" to translate but its a better practice to actually tell it what it's looking for.

Comment: You actually won't be needing the .mo file perse, but your strings definitely have to be internationalized. If they're not then not any software will be able to pick up on them.